# GTM php/js cookie parser

Tags: parsing, google-tag-manager

How can I do parsing with the Google Tag Manager, like I can do it with Universal Google Analytics
http://lsperformance.pl/blog/google-analytics-i-parsowanie-plikow-cookies/?

Comment: Don't post links to polish sites.

Comment: u dont like polish ? :)
see program code on the page, not polish words

Comment: Taa. ja lubiec polska jezyk :P //sorry, but this looks just like a spam. try to improve your question. and welcome on SO.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the linked page will not work with Universal Analytics (it parses the utmz cookie for campaign data. the utmz Cookie does not exist in Universal Analytics (which has a _ga cookie which only holds the client id. Campaign data is added only on the server depending on the traffic source for the first page in the visit). So for this specific example, you can't.

Cookie parsing in general with the Google tag manager works in two ways, depending on what you want to achieve.

Either you create a custom html tag and drop your javascript in there.

If you just want to fire tags based on cookie values you create a macro with the type "1st party cookie", this will hold the first value in the 1st party cookie of the cookie name entered in the name field (for use in a rule this might be enough).